# Accesing C# Form textbox from another class file

Tags: c#, forms, file, class, controls

I want to access Form1 elements from another class file (chartscopier.cs for example), but I can't change textbox1 text from chartscopier.cs.

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var CopyCharts = new System.Threading.Timer(chartscopier.CopyGraph, null, 0, 60000);
        }
    }
}
```

**chartscopier.cs**

```
namespace TEST
{
    class chartscopier
    {
        //var Timer = new Timer(CopyGraph, null, 0, 60000);
        public static void CopyGraph(object data)
        {
            Stopwatch strTimer = new Stopwatch();
            WebClient WC = new WebClient();
            IConfigSource BaseConfig = new IniConfigSource(@"D:\NEWROBOT\CONFIG.ini");
            string LogDir = BaseConfig.Configs["GENERAL"].Get("Log Dir");
            string ImgDir = BaseConfig.Configs["GENERAL"].Get("IMG Dir");
            string[] Clients = BaseConfig.Configs["CLIENTS"].GetKeys();
            foreach (string Client in Clients)
            {
                strTimer.Start();
                //Console.WriteLine(Client);
                IConfigSource ClientConfig = new IniConfigSource(@"D:\NEWROBOT\" + Client + ".ini");
                string[] Services = ClientConfig.Configs["SERVICES"].GetKeys();
                foreach (string Service in Services)
                {
                    string url = BaseConfig.Configs["CLIENTS"].Get(Client);
                    string param = ClientConfig.Configs["SERVICES"].Get(Service);
                    string html = WC.DownloadString(url + param);

                    // Cargar doc en HPACK
                    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(html);

                    // LINQ para generar imagenes
                    var img = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[1]");
                    var src = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
                    string uIMG = url + src;
                    WC.DownloadFile(uIMG, @ImgDir + Client + "\\" + Service + ".png");
                }
                strTimer.Stop();
                TimeSpan ts = strTimer.Elapsed;
                string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                strTimer.Reset();
                // WANT TO WRITE HERE Form1.TextBox1.text = "RunTime " + elapsedTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, a better way is to handle through events.

Create a class to represent data that you want to pass.

```
public class ChartCopyProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }
  //you can add more prop.s here
}
```

In "chartscopier" create an event to report progress.

```
class chartscopier
{
 public static event EventHandler<ChartCopyProgressEventArgs> Changed;
 public static void CopyGraph(object data)
 {
 ...
 if (Changed != null)
 {
   var args = new ChartCopyProgressEventArgs();
   args.ElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
   Changed(null, args);
 }
 }
}
```

Then in Form1, create a handler for that event.

```
public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 chartscopier.Changed += UpdateStatus;
 ...
}

private void UpdateStatus(object sender, ChartCopyProgressEventArgs e)
{ 
    var ts = e.ElapsedTime;
    var elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    var str = "RunTime " + elapsedTime;

    if (TextBox1.InvokeRequired) {
        TextBox1.Invoke(() => {TextBox1.text = str;});
    } else {
         TextBox1.text = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Note that if the type of the `event` was `Action<TimeSpan>` it would significantly reduce the code bloat.

Comment: It throws me an error when calling `if(Changed != null)` **An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'** :S

Comment: ahh.. static..sorry about that. please check now. also fixed the event raising code.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked, but I needed to fix this `TextBox1.Invoke(() => {TextBox1.text = str;});` into this `TextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { TextBox1.Text = str; });` also the `text` for `Text` (capitalize)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the form to that function so you have access to it, then write a public function on the form to modify/get the text box. Make sure the two functions are checking if invoke is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference you want `chartscopier.CopyGraph` to manipulate directly to the method so it can be within scope. Your `CopyGraph(object data)` signature should be more like `CopyGraph(object data, TextBox aTextBox)`

Then you can call it from your Form1's instance like

```
chartscopier.CopyGraph(data,this.textBox1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will show you how to access form elements from other class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormCopier fc = new FormCopier();
            fc.PopulateTest(this.textBox1);
        }
    }
```

And in other class..

```
class FormCopier
{
    public void PopulateTest(TextBox t)
    {
        t.Text = "Demo";
        t.Refresh();
    }
}
```